# Node.js read stream not reading properly from file

Tags: node.js, stream

I have a file that has one line with an id I need to use. In this case the id is on the first line of the file and it is this 
    9e598f1c-62d4-4b39-ac2d-ca8c5611c6b7

But when I try to read from the file using a read stream with this code

```
  var file_stream = fs.createReadStream(file_path);

  file_stream.on('readable', () => {
  console.log('readable:', file_stream.read());
  });

  file_stream.on('end', () => {
  console.log('end');
  });
```

I get this output

```
readable: <Buffer 39 65 35 39 38 66 31 63 2d 36 32 64 34 2d 34 62 33 39 2d 61 63 32 64 2d 63 61 38 63 35 36 31 31 63 36 62 37>
readable: null
end
```

Which is definitely not what I had in the file. What could be happening?

Comment: **bolav** gave you the answer but for one line of data, don't be ashamed to use `fs.readFileSync()`: `var content = fs.readFileSync(file_path).toString();`.

Comment: @ShanShan I ended up using this option since I need to read several lines later so thank you! Both answers pretty much served their purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the contents of your file, just in byte notation. Try this to get it back:

```
file_stream.on('readable', () => {
  var buf = file_stream.read()
  if (buf != null) {
    console.log('readable:', buf.toString());
  }
});
```